# Twitter Bootstrap .on('show',function(){}); not working for popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide all other popovers when a new popover is selected by doing the following:

My HTML

```
a.btn#requests(rel='popover',data-placement='bottom',data-original-title='<b>Requests</b>',data-content='My content goes here')
```

My Javascript

```
  $(function (){
    console.log('start');
    $('#requests').popover();
    $('#messages').popover();

  });

  //This doesn't work for some reason?
  $('#requests').on('show', function (e) {
    console.log('requests');
    $('#messages').popover('hide');
  });

  $('#messages').on('show', function () {
    console.log('messages');
    $('#requests').popover('hide');
  });
```

However, my console.log('requests') and console.log('messages'); is never getting shown even though the requests and messages popovers are showing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about the fact that it's out of the *onDomReady* call : `$(function (){})` ?

Comment: I tried that, but that didn't change anything - it shouldn't need to be there from my understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The popover plugin doesn't trigger any event. Neither does the tooltip plugin (since popover extends tooltip). Check [this issue (github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2150) for alternatives.

You can use different JS events depending on your `trigger`. For your example : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/dzkCz/)

```js
$(function (){
    console.log('start');
    $('#requests').popover();
    $('#messages').popover();

    $('#requests').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('requests');
        $('#messages').popover('hide');
    });

    $('#messages').on('click', function () {
        console.log('messages');
        $('#requests').popover('hide');
    });

});
```

Why `'click'` ? Because the default popover trigger for version 2.1.1 is `click`. See [the popover doc (github)](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)

You can use the following events :

- `trigger: 'click'` : on `click`
- `trigger: 'hover'` : display on `mouseenter` and hide on `mouseleave`
- `trigger: 'focus'` : display on `focus` and hide on `blur`
- `trigger: 'manual'` : use your own code to display and hide anyway

Answer (score 22):

Bootstrap now supports popover events - see the Events section in the [official popover docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) (and [here's the doc changelog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/7936f1478028fb759781014a2c93884f5f90a598)).

Example:

```
$('#requests')
.popover()
.on('show.bs.popover', function() { console.log('o hai'); })
.on('hidden.bs.popover', function() { console.log('ciao'); });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it by using class and haveing less and more organazied codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn').popover();

    $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.btn').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
});
```

check my [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/vFDSZ/3/)

and if you want to have form control inside customize this code:

```
var mycontent = '<div class="btn-group"> <button class="btn">Left</button> <button class="btn">Middle</button> <button class="btn">Right</button> </div>'

$('.btn').popover({
        content:mycontent,
        trigger: 'manual'
}).click(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
    e.stopPropagation();
});


   $('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
       $('.btn').not(this).popover('hide');
    });
});
```

check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/moalla/fsRaN/6/)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-events the name of the event is

> show.bs.popover

I tried it, and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            $(document).on('click', function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).is('[data-original-title]')) {
                    $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide'); 
                }
            });

            $(document).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) { 
                $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide'); 
            });
```

This sets a event handler on the whole document and if it's not a popover element it will hide all popovers.

Also, on the event show.bs.popover (triggered prior to opening a popover) it will hide all others.

Answer (score 0):

It's `.on('shown')` not `.on('show')`

Comment: Great comment, I think this may be new to twitter bootstrap. This is a very outdated question at this point.